# Populating fields from a record and allowing them to be editable

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am attempting to rig a data entry (not actually flagged for data entry, an append query looks at all the fields and adds them when the form is closed) form in Access 2007 that allows a user to pre-populate fields with results from a query, and then I would like all of the fields to be editable. I believe that my fields are not editable because they have a row source from a select query.

Can I make a form that pre-populates data in fields that can also be edited before my final append query adds the fields as a new record?

Comment: I would set your query as a recordset, then you can modify the data from the table.

Comment: Are you using an unbound form? Pass Through Query? ADO? Or why do you have an append query?